# How to NOT select this but anything else in Regexr?

Tags: javascript, string, match

I have this string made up for a TMS program... I later found out I want the program to NOT select these postalcodes, it's now matching the string. I want it to be able to select anything between `1000-10000\s*a-zA-Z` except for this:

```
(8388|8389|8390|8391|8392|8393|8394|8395|8396|8397|8398|8400|8401|8403|8404|8405|8406|8407|8408|8409|8410|8411|8412|8413|8414|8415|8420|8421|8422|8423|8424|8425|8426|8427|8428|8430|8431|8432|8433|8434|8435|8440|8441|8442|8443|8444|8445|8446|8447|8448|8449|8451|8452|8453|8454|8455|8456|8457|8458|8459|8461|8462|8463|8464|8465|8466|8467|8468|8469|8470|8471|8472|8474|8475|8476|8477|8478|8479|8481|8482|8483|8484|8485|8486|8487|8488|8489|8490|8491|8493|8494|8495|8497|8500|8501|8502|8503|8505|8506|8507|8508|8511|8512|8513|8514|8515|8516|8517|8520|8521|8522|8523|8524|8525|8526|8527|8528|8529|8530|8531|8532|8534|8535|8536|8537|8538|8539|8541|8542|8550|8551|8552|8553|8554|8556|8560|8561|8563|8564|8565|8566|8567|8571|8572|8573|8574|8581|8582|8583|8584|8600|8601|8602|8603|8604|8605|8606|8607|8608|8611|8612|8613|8614|8615|8616|8617|8618|8620|8621|8622|8623|8624|8625|8626|8627|8628|8629|8631|8632|8633|8635|8636|8637|8641|8642|8644|8647|8650|8651|8658|8700|8701|8702|8710|8711|8713|8715|8721|8722|8723|8724|8730|8731|8732|8733|8734|8735|8736|8737|8741|8742|8743|8744|8745|8746|8747|8748|8749|8751|8752|8753|8754|8755|8756|8757|8758|8759|8761|8762|8763|8764|8765|8766|8771|8772|8773|8774|8775|8800|8801|8802|8804|8805|8806|8807|8808|8809|8811|8812|8813|8814|8816|8821|8822|8823|8830|8831|8832|8833|8834|8835|8841|8842|8843|8844|8845|8850|8851|8852|8853|8854|8855|8856|8857|8860|8861|8862|8871|8872|8880|8881|8882|8883|8884|8885|8890|8891|8892|8893|8894|8895|8896|8897|8899|8900|8901|8902|8903|8911|8912|8913|8914|8915|8916|8917|8918|8919|8921|8922|8923|8924|8925|8926|8927|8931|8932|8933|8934|8935|8936|8937|8938|8939|8941|9001|9003|9004|9005|9006|9007|9008|9009|9011|9012|9013|9014|9021|9022|9023|9024|9025|9026|9027|9031|9032|9033|9034|9035|9036|9037|9038|9040|9041|9043|9044|9045|9047|9050|9051|9053|9054|9055|9056|9057|9060|9061|9062|9063|9064|9067|9071|9072|9073|9074|9075|9076|9077|9078|9079|9081|9082|9083|9084|9086|9087|9088|9089|9091|9100|9101|9102|9103|9104|9105|9106|9107|9108|9109|9111|9112|9113|9114|9121|9122|9123|9124|9125|9131|9132|9133|9134|9135|9136|9137|9138|9141|9142|91439144|9145|9146|9147|9148|9150|9151|9152|9153|9154|9155|9156|9160|9161|9162|9163|9164|9166|9171|9172|9173|9174|9175|9176|9177|9178|9200|9201|9202|9203|9204|9205|9206|9207|9211|9212|9213|9214|9215|9216|9217|9218|9219|9221|9222|9223|9230|9231|9233|9240|9241|9243|9244|9245|9246|9247|9248|9249|9250|9251|9254|9255|9256|9257|9258|9260|9261|9262|9263|9264|9265|9269|9270|9271|9280|9281|9283|9284|9285|9286|9287|9288|9289|9290|9291|9292|9293|9294|9295|9296|9297|9298|9299|9851|9852|9853|9871|9872|9873|9950)\s*[a-zA-Z]{2}
```

I obviously tried the `[^]` function and the `?:` function but I can't get it working properly.

Comment: You could use a negative lookahead https://regex101.com/r/qRpu6g/1

Answer (score 0):

Just break this string into a set(I think slice function can do that) then sort it and every time you get a value match if it exists in this set or not.

Comment: Hello, thanks for the quick answer! I'm a real noob so... How do I do that? I've been busy with this for hours now hehe... Is the answer so obvious?

Answer (score 0):

Lets make it easier, I am guessing you are getting numbers in string format of some sort with some form of separation in this case "|".
Step one create array by splinting string based on separator
Step two use filter function that will return a new array based on conditions you provide as shown in example.

Below example takes into consideration edge cases e.g. we are only comparing numbers alphabets are of lesser comparative value to us. What we have to make sure is any comparative value starts with number rest is is all gibberish. So extract number and run bit of magic on that.

Your sting was too long I have used a hypothetical scenario to give you what you want. Rest should be self explanatory in example.

```js
data = '100|999|1000|s1000|10d00|1000f|2500|7500|10000|10001|10500';
dataArray = data.split("|");
dataFiltered = dataArray.filter(function (item) {
extractedNumber = item.match(/^\d+/g);
if(extractedNumber > 999 && extractedNumber <10001) {
return item;
}})
console.log(dataFiltered)
```

to check on whats being extracted run following and update function as needed.

```js
data = '100|999|1000|s1000|10d00|1000f|2500|7500|10000|10001|10500';
dataArray = data.split("|");
dataFiltered = dataArray.filter(function (item) {
extractedNumber = item.match(/^\d+/);
console.log(extractedNumber);
if(extractedNumber > 999 && extractedNumber <10001) {
return item;
}})
console.log(dataFiltered)
```